# Get Values from Xml belong to Parent

Tags: c#, xml

I have question to reading, parsing xml File. 
Case: program reads XML, which is choosen from OpenFileDialog. This works fine, 
program reads all nodes. But my issue is here: I have ID (145, 175) - as parents nodes, under  both of them are four transactions, but program loops through whole xml and put all 8 transactions under both:

[image]

my Code (snippet):

```
Stream myStream = null;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "path_of_my_File";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;


if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            XmlReader xmlFile;
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(path, new XmlReaderSettings());
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
            int i = 0;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Transaction", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value2", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value3", typeof(string));
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(path);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/statement/retailers/retailer");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                XmlNodeList nodeList2 = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/statement/retailers/retailer/terminals/terminal/transactions");
                DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();
                dtrow["ID"] = node.Attributes["ID"].Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);

                foreach (XmlNode node2 in nodeList2)
                {
                    dtrow = dt.NewRow();

                    dtrow["Date"] = node2["transaction"].Attributes["date"].Value;
                    dtrow["Transaction"] = node2["transaction"].Attributes["transaction"].Value;
                    dtrow["Value1"] = node2["transaction"].Attributes["Value1"].Value;
                    dtrow["Value2"] = node2["transaction"].Attributes["Value2"].Value;
                    dtrow["Value3"] = node2["transaction"].Attributes["Value3"].Value;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);
                }
            }

            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

How can I say: put only Transaction belonging to parent (4 transactions under 145 and four under 175?)

Dummy XML for structure:

```
<root>
<factory name ="145">
    <id name = "xxx" value1 ="b" value2 ="b" value3 ="b" >
</factory>
<factory name ="175">
    <id name = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" value1 ="c" value2 ="c" value3 ="c" >
</factory>
</root>
```

Comment: Why call `xmldoc.SelectNodes` for transactions, instead of `node.SelectNodes` ?

Comment: No, just using tutorial with  XmlReader :)  which  one xDocument or XmlDocument is better ?

Comment: That's a matter of opinion, I use `XDocument`, because it is newer, provides the same functionality and provides LINQ2XML.

Comment: I prefer XDocument because it is easier to use.  With XmlDocument you have to declare elements and then add to the elements where in XDocument you can often combine two XmlDocument instructions into a single instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your second `SelectNodes`, you are applying the respective XPath expression on the entire document instead of the selected sub-node. To select from the sub-node, use:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList2 = node.SelectNodes("./terminals/terminal/transactions");
```

Comment: Perfect, it is solution for my problem.